# Order of the volume growth of logarithmic spherical wedge

Tags: multivariable-calculus, asymptotics, volume

I'm trying to find the volume growth of a wedge cut from a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

In particular the constraints are:
$$-log(z+1)^2 \leq x \leq log(z+1)^2,$$
$$-z \leq y \leq z,$$
$$x^2+y^2+z^2\leq r^2.$$

I'm expecting the volume to be of order $\Omega(r^2)$ but I'm struggling with the computation.

The problem where $x$ is bounded by a general smooth, positive, increasing function of $z$ is also of interest. ie
$$-f(z) \leq x \leq f(z),$$
$$-z \leq y \leq z,$$
$$x^2+y^2+z^2\leq r^2.$$

I wonder what's an useful technique to deal with these computations?

Comment: $O(r^2)$ is clear since the volume of the ball $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq r^2$ is already bounded by $O(r^2)$. Do you mean $\Omega(r^2)$, i.e., the volume is lower and upper bounded by a constant times $r^2$?

Comment: yes thanks I meant $\Omega(r^2)$